# US Power Supply for Antminer s9

Tags: mining-hardware, antminer

I have ordered Antminer S9. After doing some research I discovered that [APW3+-12-1600 PSU 1600W](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N8UDFTF) is a recommended power supply however it requires 200+ voltage which is not available to me.

I live in the US and the standard wall socket output voltage is 110V.

Could you recommend a power supply that  would work well with S9 in the US without impeding its designed performance?

A recommendation or a reference to a working guide would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote, as the asker specifically tells us what the problem is he wants to solve and what he tried before. The product recommendation questions we don't want are: "What is the best X today?" The ones along the lines of "I need any solution to solve problem P, XYZ didn't work" are okay.— Recommendations in answer MUST solve asker's problem and explain how they arrive at recommendation.

Comment: This a valid question that I am looking for an answer to. Agree with Murch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question and hopefully it will come in handy for someone else.

While I understand that it might be a bit of an overkill pricewise but this solution works for me and has been working for 6 month now.

I power each of mine Antminer S9 with **EVGA SuperNOVA 1600 T2 80+ TITANIUM**

This is how it looks at home https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3c2FBScdjk and at a data center: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EfgCPPlDYPw

Answer (score 4):

I live in North America as well and just wanted to let you know that even though 110V is the most common wall socket voltage you've actually already got 220V coming in to your house.  There are 2 110V lines 180° out of phase from the other ... yadda yadda, some technical mumbo-jumbo...

Long story short, as long as you live in a building where you have access to the breaker box you should be able to add in a 220V circuit to power your miners, you may already have a couple in there for an electric range or drier, etc.

If electrical work is not your forte you should be able to get an electrician in to get you set up fairly easily, the hardest part is deciding where you want to access the power from and then routing the wiring there.

Hope that helps!

-J

Comment: thanks James, as it turns out I was unable to run a miner in my apartment at all: 1: heat and noise are not acceptable for a residential setting 2: I do not have an available electric rail that is capable of supporting this power consumption. I am already running microwave and AC on separate rails. I ended up renting a space in a data center. But I was more concerned with a model of a power supply I could get to power an S9 (which turns out to be EVGA 1600)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

I was running AntminerS9 on 120 volt without any problem but it will consume almost 12 Amps. Normal home supply is only 100Amps so in order to save amps I had to change it to 220 volt by installing new circuit breaker. With 220 volt it will consume only 6Amps (approx)

Comment: Power = Current x Voltage --> 6 Amps @ 220V = 1320 W , 12 Amps @ 120V = 1440 W --> so yes, the efficiency of the AC to DC  power supply converter apparently is working at a better operational point but to get 220V you are probably running through a voltage transformer (120->220) which considering an Ideal No loss Transformer, on the lower voltage side coil will still be consuming 1320 W / 120V --> 11 Amps.

Comment: In North America, virtually every home has two 120 volt phases that can be combined into a 240 volt supply with no power loss.

Answer (score 0):

In North America, the two halves (each 120 V nominal) are NOT out of phase.  They are simple the top and bottom halves of a center-tapped transformer sitting outside on a pole or in a big green box on the ground.  Go outside and look at it.  The power company gives you one wire (plus a ground) to their transformer and two (plus a ground) leaving it going to your house.  The coil on the half of the transformer facing you is tapped to ground ("earth" in non-American English) in the center with nominally 240V across the whole transformer, and 120V on each wire. This has nothing to do with phase. The other side of the transformer (facing the line) has at least 7000V (or as much as 45,000V), and is tapped on one end - with the other end going to a SINGLE WIRE for a single phase from the power line.  If you see three wires plus a fourth one below, you are looking at three phases, but unless you are in an industrial setting (Lathes, BIG welders, mills, data centers, etc.) only one wire comes into your home or apartment building.  If there are three phases going into a building, you will see three transformers on the pole or poles.  Look at it and see - all the outside wires are exposed and you can photo them with your phone from the ground and zoom in to trace the wires.

Once inside, the breaker box, or panel or sub-panel will have a main breaker (kills all the other ones).  The number of Amps rated on that main will be the 80% of the max loadable Amps at 240V (nominal) and the total Wattage is that number times 240V.  In other words, if you follow this so far, you can fully load TWICE that many amps at 110/120V - assuming constant load and even distribution across smaller breakers.  Note also that every breaker (by code/law) has 20% leeway between the label and the actual trip amperage, (again, don't trust me, pull one out and look at the label on it) so if you have 200Amp sub panel for your house or condo, you might be able to get 440Amps of 120V equipment loaded before things start to smoke.  Keep in mind, mfg tolerances, age, loose screws or push connections, etc. AND, while you are reading the 20%, etc on the side of that breaker, you will note that it will have been made in Mexico at a location in a state that does not enforce a minimum wage or allow effective union negotiations - so figure that into the tolerances.  In other words, if you push it anywhere close to the maximums, you should not sleep where you mine, and you should have good fire insurance - especially the liability portion.

25 years building data centers.